# Not connected pin in Orcad Capture

Tags: orcad

I have a pot (R8), as you can see, C6 capacitor is connected to its middle terminal, I have trouble implementing this in Orcad as it says that the negative terminal of the capacitor is connected to nowhere, I tried placing a `No Connect`, it didn't work, then connected it to GND and the error went away.

But is connecting that terminal to GND technically correct or it would distort the result?

[image]

Comment: Have you made the symbol yourself? Did you use the same grid as in your schematic? A grid mismatch is usually the reason for not being able to connect a component terminal in the schematic.

Comment: No, I've taken it from one my assignments.

Comment: put a 1000 Meg resistor across the output terminals

Comment: If that pin is your output, then you need to tell Orcad that there is some sort of pad or connector there.

Answer (score 1):

The "not connected" message is just a warning, not an error. Orcad is telling you the negative terminal of C6 is connected to nowhere because it is connected to nowhere. That is the final output of your circuit so you certainly don't want to ground it.

How do you plan to access the output in the physical world? Usually it would be via a jack (1/4" or 1/8" audio jack, RCA jack, etc) or perhaps just a testpoint. You need to put that on your schematic and connect C6 to that.

If this is only for simulation you can ignore the warning, leave it unconnected and just use the capacitor pin as your simulator output.

Advice: put a resistor to ground on your output - this sets the DC level to zero. Without it a simulator will get fussy.

Answer (score 0):

Just press X (Not connected) or menu>place>no connect and click at the pin.